# Distributing Cookbooks to Team Members

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, test-kitchen

Using `test-kitchen` and `Berkshelf`, I'd like to capture & distribute my current cookbooks.

After telling teammates to install `berkshelf`, these options seem possible:

1. retrieve cookbooks via the opscode repo per `Berksfile` cookbook
2. run `berks package` to tar-ball all necessary cookbooks. Then, developers would unzip the tarball, then their Berksfile would retrieve each cookbook via `cookbook X, path: 'cookbooks/X'`
3. ???

Which option is the best and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to distribute the cookbooks? The entire point of tools like Berkshelf/Bundler is so that you **don't** have to share cookbooks.

When you install your cookbooks with Berkshelf, Berkshelf will generate a lockfile. This lockfile contains the list of all the cookbooks and their location. Then you check in that lockfile to source control. When your teammates clone/update the repository, they will get that lockfile. When then run `berks install`, Berkshelf will honor all the constraints and versions from the lockfile.

Non-standard locations (i.e. path, github, svn, hg, etc) are highly discouraged. They make solving the graph nearly impossible and make your repository less portable.

See also:

- [Supermarket](https://github.com/opscode/supermarket)
- [Berkshelf Vision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq_vGxd-jps&list=PL11cZfNdwNyMmx0msapJfuGsLV43C7XsA&index=16)

Sources:

- Core team

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I appreciate the "Berkshelf Vision" talk too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the best choice boils down to who you intend to distribute your cookbooks to.

1. Other developers?

   - Simpliest solution would be to commit your Berkfile.lock alongside your code
   - Captures dependencies at a point in time
2. 3rd parties

   - Create a tarball (using Berkshelf) and upload to a binary repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).
   - Users can download an explicit copy of the cookbooks used in your chef server. Useful if customer is behind a corporate firewall.

Jamie Windsor discusses various approaches in his blog posting:

- [Environment cookbook pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. So, let's say I do: `rm -rf Berksfile.lock && 'create & provision box'`. If that run works successfully, then I can commit my `Berksfile.lock` to source control to force developers to use a particular version? What if someone updates the `Berksfile`? Does that override the `Berksfile.lock`? Thanks